# How do I enable Jenkins admin user when using Active Directory login

Tags: jenkins

I have recently switched to using AD login on my Jenkins instance but I notice Jenkins has restricted the functionalities I can access including the Manage Jenkins view:

[image: JENKINS]

I can no longer login with the admin user after this re-configuration since it returns incorrect password from the Active Directory.

Did I miss something else in configuring AD authentication ?
If so what because the guide I followed was straight-forward and has no mention of using the built-in database users. I am not sure either if my permissions will be linked to my AD group ( my AD user is not in Admin group).

I am also not sure on whether Jenkins continues supporting login with the admin user after you have enabled AD authentication.

Answer (score 1):

So this will come down to you Authorization Plugin and what you have setup there.

If you are using the Role Based Strategy and haven't granted your user Admin permissions then it is correct for you have not got them.

When setting up the Active Directory Plugin in the Advanced menu there is an option for `Use Jenkins Internal Database` which allows

```
This option allows to fallback into the Jenkins Internal User Database for the specific user selected (ONLY ONE USER).
```

You could select this option and set your built in user (or admin) as the fallback.

If you are currently totally locked out you can edit the `config.xml` and set  `<useSecurity>` to false and restart the Jenkins process which will remove the Active Directory config